# Using Air Intake Cleaners

Tags: maintenance, cleaning, air-intake

I cleaned the air intake spraying a **Sonax liquid air intake cleaner**.
I took off the air filter, sprayed, waited to get dry and started the engine. It works well in my car that I think it was clean before because it has 20.000 km (around 12500 miles). I did the same process later in a friend's car, but the engine didn't start quickly. I needed to push the accelerator pedal for some seconds while trying to start the engine.
Why it didn't started instantly? Maybe the liquid didn't complete dry? Maybe the intake was too dirty?

Comment: Did it start okay after the first try? If so, don't worry about it.

Comment: It started the first time but it took some seconds and it started when I push the accelerator pedal. I would like to know why it didn't happend in my car and if other people had the same situation.

Comment: Different cars; different situations. You could even do the same thing to your car again and have different results. As for my question: Did it start okay after the first try?

Comment: @Paulster2 it started okay after first try.

Comment: The problem could have been any or none of the reasons you stated. As long as it is running correctly now, I wouldn't worry about it. This is not really an answer, but hoping to quell any fears you may have ... thus leaving it in the comment section. Another thing to think about here is, if the vehicle in question is fuel injected, it's not good to depress the throttle when starting the engine. In some vehicles it can actually screw some things up. Just a word of caution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to wait a few minutes more to completely let it dry.

Answer (score 2):

Since the car started fine after the first try, there should be nothing to worry about. The thing to remember is: different car; different situation. If it continued not to want to start, then you'd have an issue.